# How to compare props in ComponentDidUpdate for large data structure connected with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been working with new lifecycles of React v16. It works great when we compare only a single key. But when it comes to compare a large data structures like an Arrays of objects, the deep comparison will become very costly.

I have use case like this in which I have an array ob objects stored in redux,

```
const readings =[
{
id: ...,
name: ...',
unit:...,
value: ...,
timestamp: ...,
active: true,
 },
 ...
]
```

Whenever active state of any objects get changed I dispatch an action to update redux state to be same for all connected components with that reducer.

```
class Readings extends Component {
  state = {
    readings:[],
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if ( // comparsion of readings array with prevState) {
      return {
        readings: nextProps.readings,
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if ( // comparsion of readings array with prevState) {
      // perform an operation here to manipulate new props and setState to re render the comp
      // this causes infinite loop
    }
  }

  render() {
   ...
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  readings: state.readings.readings,
});


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(Readings));
```

How can I avoid infinite loop on setState in componentDidUpdate, I don't want to do deep comparison of readings array. Is there a better solution to handle this case?

Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought - do you need to derive state here, why not just keep it in props? Also, what do you do with the readings? Perhaps you could restructure to remove the need for a deep comparison. If you display something for each reading, why not have a `<Reading />` component for each of them. This could be a `PureComponent` and  each `<Reading />` can shallow compare the object reference, with no need for a deep comparison in the parent.

Comment: yes you're right. Keeping only props solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ideally, you make immutable changes to your reducer and keep the
>   reducer state level low.

So if your array consists of many objects and you need to dispatch based on some attribute change, you should replace the whole readings array using spread operator or using some immutable library e.g immutablejs. Then in your componentDidupdate you can have something like :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   const {
     readings,
   } = this.props
   const {
     readings: prevReadings,
   } = prevProps
  if (readings !== prevReadings) {
      //dispatch something
  }
}
```

Thanks feedbacks are welcome.

Comment: But this would do deep comparison too? Or this would be a reference comparison?

Comment: When you do an immutable change, reference changes. That's how this condition will work. yeah changing reference

Comment: you're destructuring readings and prevReadings both from this.props?

Comment: But how would you compare it in getDerivedStateFromProps? We don’t have access to This in that lifecycle. What’s happening is it works great for componentDidUpdate when I setState in this lifeCycle and getDerivedStateProps hasn’t this key word to access this.props. It compare prevState with nextProps

Comment: Yeah ideally you need to make the side effects in componentDidUpdate. That will solve the issue. Why not in getDerivedStateFromProps ?  read it here. there are many reasons which are explained here properly https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. It has solved my problem. I don't need derived state lifecylce here.

Comment: For deeply nested objects with many properties could you do this?
`if (JSON.stringify(this.props.readings) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps.readings)) { ... }`

Answer (score -1):

**First read another answer, If that didn't work for you, then:**

1. Make sure you're comparing two arrays with :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if(JSON.stringify(prevProps.todos) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.todos){...}
}
```

2. Make sure you are changing the passed prop (state in parent) after **deep cloning** it:

```
let newtodos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.todos));
newtodos[0].text = 'changed text';
this.setState({ todos : newtodos });
```

(Note that Shallow clone doesn't work, since that way you change the objects directly)